# Users created to Ubuntu by Puppet cannot connect by SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, puppet

I am trying to add new user to Ubuntu Server 14.04 with the latest version Puppet.

I use the following code:

```
 user { 'user':
            ensure => present,
            home => '/home/user',
            managehome => true,
            password => 'password',
            system => true,
            shell =>  '/bin/bash',
            require => Group['usergroup'],
    }
```

The user gets created successfully but cannot log in with SSH.

This is what I get when trying to SSH:

```
user@10.11.11.11's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 54 padlen 10 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Problem should not be about allowing users to use SSH because user created with 
**adduser** can log in with SSH without problems. Also all existing user can SSH in.

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: the password in puppet should be in encrypted format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the password in puppet should be in encrypted format

for example:

```
  class adminusers {
     group { 'mygroup':
            ensure => 'present',
            gid    => '900',
       }

      user { 'pippo':
            ensure   => 'present',
            gid      => '100',
            home     => '/home/pippo',
            shell    => '/bin/bash',
            uid      => '150',
            managehome => true,
            groups => ['mygroup'],
            password => '$1$WhUZgOHI$OerslOWA3aeZfRjemFsvl/',
            require => Group['mygroup'],
        }
     }
```